# Does sbt-native-package docker plugin support to create a tag

Tags: docker, sbt-native-packager

Does sbt-native-package docker plugin support to create a tag ?

Is there a way to show the available commands of sbt-native-package docker?
it seems the doc is far from complete

Answer (score 0):

> Does sbt-native-package docker plugin support to create a tag ?

Nope. There is only an `dockerUpdateLatest`, which overrides the `latest` tag. If you need this feature, create an issue or better a pull request :)

> Is there a way to show the available commands of sbt-native-package docker?

The [docker docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html) give a complete overview over all `task` and `settings`. The sbt-native-packager is a very thin wrapper around the actual docker cli tool.

> it seems the doc is far from complete

The [docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html) contain how to use the plugin, all settings and tasks with explanations and different ways how you can customize your build if the predefined settings aren't enough for you. However we don't document things we don't do. That's what the issues are for.

And if the normal docs aren't enough, you can also have a look at the [scaladocs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/latest/api/#com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.package), which are less extensive, but you have a complete look at the code.

Hope that helps,
Muki

Comment: Thanks, Muki, Very detailed answer. I tried to set my own release version when using sbt release, and finally, I found it is possible to embedded scala code like 'set ReleaseVersion := {ver => "1.1.1"} ' to do that.  So, that's why I ask this question. Thank you very much again.